# Adding jar files in the WEB-INF/lib folder

Tags: java, eclipse, path

I am using spring MVC validation for my login form in eclipse.

Here i want to add my jar files (Hibernate-validator,javax.validator etc..) into the **lib** folder in the **WEB CONTENT**.But if every time i add it will get into *Javascript Resources*.

I do found these question in forum but still cant get the right answer.Can any suggest me want i have to do.

Comment: How are you adding them to the lib folder ?

Comment: I just did Right click on the lib->bulid path -> configure build path and then add external jars TAB.

Comment: How old is your version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Check if any copy of it is actually physically being copied to your javascript resoures at runtime. If so there might be some setup which is doing so, otherwise there is no possibility of your jar files being copied to your javascript resources.

Comment: i gets added into java resource after i configure jars in the bulid path itself not while in the run time.

Comment: If you are placing your jar files into WEB-INF/lib folder, then there is no need of setting your jars in build path.

Comment: yes buddy my ques is how can i add jars in lib folder.